# switchMap then merge not working

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular app, I route to a component. Inside that component, I want to display an `item$` observable.

Now, if my service has a cached item, use that, and regardless, request an item from the backend. So the experience might be to show the cached item for a moment, then the backend item replaces it after it loads. If the item doesn't exist on the backend, the cached item would be the only emitted value. If it's not, we show a not found.

Here's how I have tried to execute this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.item$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.id = params.get('id'); // get the id
        if (this.service.item && this.id === this.service.item.id) {
          return of(this.service.item); // cached item
        }
        return of(null); // nothing cached
      }),
      merge(this.backend.getItem(this.id)) // get backend item
    );
  }
```

my template code

```
<div *ngIf="item$ | async as item; else showNotFound">
  <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
  <!-- other props omitted -->
</div>
<ng-template #showNotFound>
  <p>Not found</p>
</ng-template>
```

However, merge fires before switchMap and cannot get the item because `this.id` is not yet set. If I move the merge in front of switchMap, switchMap can't get the param. How can this be done?

Comment: You may try to remove merge altogether and place this.backend.getItem(this.id) within switchMap, as one of the Observable returned

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.item$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.id = params.get('id'); // get the id
        return this.backend.getItem(this.id).pipe(
          map(backendResult => {
            if (backendResult === undefined) {
              if (this.service.item && this.id === this.service.item.id) {
                return this.service.item; // cached item
              }
              return null; // nothing cached
            } else {
              return backendResult;
            }
          })
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: not getting you code, you can make use of tap instead of switchMap , as you are not using value return by switchMap

Comment: previous solution wasn't working right... updated it. Now the cached result doesn't display, but it does at least fall back on the cached result.

Answer (score 0):

I supouse you want write

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.id = params.get('id'); // get the id
        if (this.service.item && this.id === this.service.item.id) {
          return of(this.service.item); // cached item
        }  
        //If not is cached
        return this.backend.getItem(this.id)
          //You can "cached" the value, here
          .pipe(tap((item)=>{this.service.item=item}
          ));
      })).subscribe((item)=>{this.item=item}); //DON'T forget subscribe
  }
```

Comment: when you async pipe something as I did in my template code, it subscribes and unsubscribes automatically